# BASH:How do i make output like in watch command

Tags: bash, watch

My linux 'watch' command is quite old and doesn't support '--color' option. How can I have same output like it does? because in my script the loop gives output one after another(of course). But i need it to replace the previous. Is there any tricks with terminal output?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "show queue My_Compain" \
| grep Agent \
| grep -v \(Unavailable\) \
| sort -t"(" -k 2 \
| GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always '^.*[0-9] \(Not in use.*$|$' \
| GREP_COLOR='01;36' egrep -i --color=always '^.*\(Busy*$|$'
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: You can add `clear` as the first line of the loop if you want the screen to appear to update in place rather than append to the old results.

Comment: @that other guy Thank you, thats the one. I wish it could work faster though without blinking

Comment: `clear` actually just sends a bunch of empty lines to the terminal forcing the old output to move up and out of view so you can not get rid of the slight blink. [`printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) can do alot with formatting terminal output and is pretty much de facto so if you want more try switching to that for output.

Comment: @Matt Green, its could be easy for single line.. is there any good example how to do that for multiply lines in bash?

Comment: @MattGreen `clear | hexdump -C` will show you that it outputs an ANSI control sequence, not a bunch of empty lines. If it did, new output would appear at the bottom of the screen, not the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clear` to clear the screen before dumping your output to give the appearance of in-place updates.

To reduce blinking, you can use the age old technique of double buffering:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  buffer=$(
    clear
    /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "show queue My_Compain" \
    | grep Agent \
    | grep -v \(Unavailable\) \
    | sort -t"(" -k 2 \
    | GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always '^.*[0-9] \(Not in use.*$|$' \
    | GREP_COLOR='01;36' egrep -i --color=always '^.*\(Busy*$|$'
  )
  echo "$buffer"
  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: yeah, absolutely. lines are vary from 0 to 100

Comment: Does it help if you add `| tail -n 20` so you don't print more lines than your terminal can show in one screenful?

Comment: Ah sorry, i didn't erase second 'clear', now it works perfect! Thank u